# Padding on parent versus margin on child

Tags: html, css

When I want to place some (logically meaningful) div inside a (logical) container div with some space apart as below,

[image: div within div with space]

which of the two ways would be more logically correct?

- Set the padding property of the container
- Set the margin property of the div that is inside

Sometimes, I have more than one element in the container like this:

[image: multiple divs within a container div]

For such cases, I would need to set the space between the elements independently from the space surrounding the elements. For the space between, I cannot use the padding property of the container, and I have to go with the margin (-left or -right) of the elements inside. Taking this into consideration, for setting the space between the container and the elements, I am wondering whether it makes more sense to set the margin (-left, -right, -top, -bottom) of the elements or the padding of the container.

I use flexbox. And I also have the setting as `box-sizing: border-box;`. I am free to use CSS selectors such `nth-child` if necessary.

Comment: This almost feels like a trick question. My gut is to set the padding of the outside container.

Comment: It depends. A margin when you want to exactly place the inner div; a padding when you want a distance between de outer div and its content(s).

Comment: If the child div is the only div then its logical to use padding since nothing will be beside it.

Comment: @AliBassam But I think the parent should not need to be aware of its children; only the child himself?

Comment: @sawa I tend to close the question, buceause it is very subjective. There doesn't exist a _correct_ answer.

Comment: @bwoebi there are many other properties concerning a parent's relation to its child, text-align, position (relative for example), I think margins should be used to make distance between childs themselves (if its more than one). Padding is much easier and safe in the case of 1 child, the box the OP showed is very similar to a profile picture on Facebook or Google+ where they use a padding between the div and the inner image which gives a framework feel of an image.

Comment: @AliBassam relative doesn't work: it'll overlap on the other side (without an explicit width).

Comment: By the way: in the last case, it is clear: padding: Npx; on the outer div and margin: Npx; on the inner, there is no big choice to not make it overly complicated.

Comment: @sawa, given your update, you should use flexbox. Unfortunately it's not supported widely enough to be a viable cross-browser solution as of yet.

Comment: @zzzzBov Thanks, I am actually using flexbox. And I also have the setting as `box-sizing: border-box;`.

Comment: @sawa: That is a massively important detail that you left out...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I prefer to set margin on the `div` that resides inside the container.

Suppose the black `div` below is the outer container with `display: flex`, `width: 300px` and `height: 200px`. When you assign `padding: 30px` padding to the outer `div`, this will result in `360px` in width and `260px` in height. Given that you won't expect the container to stretch, this will affect the elements around the container div. Hence, it is better to use margin on the inner `div`.

[image]

When you assign margin between the inner `div` and the container, the actual outer `div` won't move, and the margin will only affect the inner div, thus not affecting the elements around it.

If you are using `box-sizing: border-box;` then things will change accordingly, so it totally depends on what actual size the elements has to be. Using margin/padding on the inner elements will be the right way.

Comment: Actually, I set as `box-sizing: border-box;`.

Comment: @sawa Why change the container size? You want the space between the child div and the container, the best way to go for is margin if you want to maintain the width and height, if not, go for padding which will add the height/width to the inner element

Comment: I think neither the padding of the parent or the margin of the child adds to the width and the height of the child regardless of box-sizing.

Comment: I previously didn't understand this answer well, but it turned out that setting `padding` on a `display: flex` item interferes with its size, so I have to use `margin` on the elements inside.

Answer (score 11):

Consider what kind of gutter you want to add. Is it to seperate elements from each other? Is it to create space inside an element?

**For gutter on all sides of an element, like the blue in your example:**

[image]

Here, I'd use padding on the container. Logically, that's exactly what I want, so why consider anything else?

---

**For gutter between elements on a row, like the space between the green elements in your second example:**

[image]

Here, I'd use margin on the green elements. There's obviously a margin between them, so padding doesn't make a whole lot of sense.

---

When you use these two examples together, however, they create a problem where the margin on the green elements may be conflicting with their parent's padding. **I manage this by removing the margins from the first and last children.**

Additionally, you may want more of those fine, green elements on a new row. I usually clear on every row using an element wrapping the entire row with whatever appropriate method to clear the floats, so it makes a lot of sense to seperate the rows with a margin. Obviously, the same conflict with the parent's padding arises here, but it's easily handled in the same way (ie, removing the margin from the last row).

**So, in short:**

- Padding on parent elements for gutter between its edges and its children.
- Margin to seperate elements with the same parent from each other.
- Remove margins from said children when its margin connects to the parent's padding (the first and/or last children in a row, the last child in a column).

**Disclaimer:** This is how *I* do things. I can't promise it's the most efficient way to do things, but it's the way that makes the most sense to me.

Comment: Margins fall together on some standard CSS rules (collapse) and in my opinion it's better to know just about that (next to the box model(s)): http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins

Comment: *Adjoining, vertical* margins collapse. This never happens in my examples. :-)

Comment: It turned out that, if I set `padding` on the container, then the size of the container changes (in an unwanted way) depending on the `padding` amount. So, the only option for me is to set the `margin` on the elements inside.

Answer (score 3):

There is no hard-and-fast rule on this, because it all depends on context, and in complex designs, you usually have no choice but to use one or the other to get the desired result.

That said, you should try to group logically related rules together. For instance, when you have two HTML elements on a website that serve a similiar purpose, e.g. your outer `<div>` and another similar box (that should get no padding), then, all else being equal, it is better to *set a `margin` on the inner `<div>`.*

If, however, you are placing more than one element into the outer `<div>`, then you should in fact use a padding, because that takes care of all inner elements at once. @zzzzBov's answer works as well, but it relies on margin collapsing, which can be tricky to deal with.

edit: In your second situation, I usually combine `padding` and `margin`, like this:

```
.outer {
    padding: 10px 15px 10px 5px
}

.inner {
    margin-left: 10px
}
```

Probably looks complicated, but works regardless of margin collapsing and has served me very well.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how your subsequent content should render. If you're going to have multiple inner `<div>`s (green) separated by a similar amount of spacing, it will make sense to use `margin` so that the margin collapse allows the divs to render as:

```
+-------
|        <- blue
|  +----
|  |     <- green
|  |
|  +----
|
|  +----
|  |     <- green
|  |
|  +----
|
+-------
```

[Here is an example of some of the various options](http://jsfiddle.net/ZGuZ5/).

Comment: Yes. For those worried about parent margins collapsing with child margins, that will *not* happen if there is a border on the parent as depicted in the image.

Comment: Well, the OP has just mentioned that flexbox is in use. In that case, note that margins do not collapse between flex items at all.

Comment: Sorry about leaving the detail. Thanks for the fiddle.