# child looses margins if parent is without borders

Tags: html, css

```
<div id='wrapt'>
<img id='logoc' src='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c7/Porto_Covo_pano_April_2009-4.jpg' alt='img'>
</div>

#wrapt{
    margin-top:45px;
    position:relative;
    background:#000;
    border-bottom:2px solid red;
    border-top:2px solid red;
}
#logoc{
    display:block;
    width:50%;
    margin:25px auto;
}
```

If I remove borders from `#wrapt` (2px solid red) - `#logoc` looses its margins !
So, how to keep margins without borders on parent?

This qustion is not duplicated with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13573653/css-margin-terror-margin-adds-space-outside-parent-element).
It's not about margins/paddings on parent/child.
My question is:

Why child's margins deppends of parent's BORDERS ?

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/bonaca/p9uqvzv7/)

Comment: You still have the margin, but it is outside. You have to use padding for that case.

Comment: @Huelfe, I don't want padding on an image. The question is why margins on child deppends of parent's borders?

Comment: @bonaca this might point you in the right direction, but basically when there is no border, the margin collapses. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1762539/margin-on-child-element-moves-parent-element

Comment: @Valeklosse, ok, I see, but this is so stupid css rule, isn't it?

Comment: @bonaca - No, it's essential. Something as basic as paragraph spacing wouldn't work properly without collapsing margins.

Comment: @Alohci, I would say that it's essential borowser should recognize if something is image vs paragraph, and collaps margins on paragraph only.

Comment: @bonaca - The browser does. Images are by default inline. Their margins won't collapse. But you undermine that by assigning  them `display:block`.

Comment: @Alohci, of course, but it's still an image and not paragraph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add **padding** in **#logoc** class and remove border from **#wrapt** class

```
#logoc {
    display: block;
    width: 50%;
    margin: 25px auto;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Comment: I don't want padding on an image. The question is why margins on child deppends of parent's borders?

Comment: this link will help you to understand. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16880851/padding-on-parent-versus-margin-on-child

Comment: Your link is about margins and paddings on parent/child. There is nothing about borders. Why child's MARGINS deppends of parent's BORDERS?

Comment: @bonaca - read the first and, in particular, third answer of the question to which this is a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

```
#wrapt{
    margin-top:45px;
    position:relative;
    background:#000;
  text-align:center;
}
#logoc{
    display:inline-block;
    width:50%;
    margin:25px auto;
}
```

Using an `inline block` and `center` aligning will work, the `inline-block` adheres to the top and bottom margin.

Comment: I don't want  `text-align:center` on parent because of other elements inside. The question is why margins on child deppends of parent's borders?

Answer (score 1):

you can do it by floating these two elements and adding actual widths to both elements:

```
    #wrapt{
        margin-top:45px;
        position:relative;
        background:#000;
        float:left;
        width:100%;
    }
    #logoc{
        display:block;
        float:left;
        width:50%;
        margin:25px 25%;
    }
```

Comment: I don't want padding on an image. The question is why margins on child deppends of parent's borders? - this is because that parent item is empty, the olny content of that elements was that boarder

Comment: No, border is not a content, border is border. btw I have other elements inside, absolutely positioned, but they are not relevant here.

Comment: exactl, hence when it's set to be posioned abolute to the parent relative div without width, height or float, it's more less being couted as empty div (no content inside)